# How can I find the line of best fit with a 2d-Histogram in Python?

Tags: python

I have a 2d Histogram where the value of each bin is calculated by points per bin divided by total points inside that bins row (so occurrence percentage by row). If I am trying to create a line of best fit that goes through the denser center areas of the histogram, how could I do that?
The data I have is one numpy array stored like,

```
percentages = [[0.00209644 0.00069881 0.00279525 0.00069881 0.00139762
  0.00209644 0.00349406 0.00419287 0.00628931 0.01607268 0.01467505
  0.02166317 0.02445842 0.03214535, i, i, i, and so on]
 [0.02581665 0.02212856 0.02107482...]]
```

that is a 50 x 20 array so each bin has a value. Using these values, I made the histogram using

```
plt.pcolormesh(xEdges, yEdges, percentages)
```

So my question is, how would I create a line of best fit when this is all the information I have?

[image: 2d Histogram]

Comment: Can you adapt one of the contour examples in the [Matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#images-contours-and-fields)

Answer (score 0):

> the denser center areas of the histogram

I assume density would be the z-value - `percentages`.

- define an upper and lower bound for the values of your line, maybe .079 < percentages <= .081
- find all the points within those boundaries
- add a line using those points.
- if the line is too thick or not continuous, adjust the boundaries and repeat.

---

- determine the value that delineates inside or outside - maybe .08 percent
- use numpy's `.isclose` method, with an appropriate tolerance, to find the points close to that value
- draw a line using those points